# how to handle cookies while scraping

Tags: http, cookies, screen-scraping

I'm in the middle of making a small scraping utility which is designed
to run as quickly as possible using multiple http connections to the server.

How does one handle cookies in this situation..

For example if the first connection scrapes the page for links, and the server
sets the cookie to something,, wouldn't firing off additional connections 
cause the cookies to be out of sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it really depends on the server.

If the server changes the cookie with each and every request
yes it will throw off the cookie.  What exactly this does again
depend on the server.

If say the cookie is just set once at login, then it wouldn't really matter.

Comment: that's what i thought... -however , the reason I needed to ask is, surely googlebot must come across this issue all the time,, and it would slow their crawling process way down.. -- any ideas or suggestions for cascading queued algorithms that might be used?

Comment: Not really.  I've written scraping apps for clients, and their is no one size fit all solution.  Each one ends up being very specifically designed for just that situation.  Best solution is to use browser that you can keep an eye on the cookie values and what is being sent/received from the server and just figure out how the black box that is the server works by expirmentation.  Good Luck.